# How to validate the existence of a registry path?

Tags: c#, registry

I was wondering how can I validate the existence of a registry path?

This is the code I am using and I would like to know how I can validate the existence of `PATH`?

```
string PATH = @"SOFTWARE\GT37\0010\";
        RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(PATH);
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.path.getfullpath(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @EpicKip I am using path in the code was you can see

Comment: Your code contains a lot of stuff that is totally, totally irrelevant to your question. You need to keep it minimal so we can provide better and faster answers. Please see [ask].

Comment: @GrantWinney I am talking about the path in registry , how can I blook the catch ?

Comment: @EpicKip Can I use that in a path in the registry?

Comment: @Liam When I use the null it wont oppen the form I am using

Comment: this is not a duplicate, a `VALUE` is not a `KEY` good grief!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From description you provided it seems you want to verify that registry key

> HKCU\SOFTWARE\GT37\0010\

exists ?

Please note that User-specific settings will be written to HKCU\Software and machine-specific settings to HKLM\Software. Based on your scenario you might want to check both.
Anyhow, in order to check whether a key exists or not you just try to get it's value like this

```
var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\GT37\0010");
// if you want to check under HKLM
//var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\GT37\0010");
if (key == null)
{
    // Key does not exist
}
else
{
    // Key exists proceed with your logic
}
```